# cant get proper redirect

Tags: html, css

```
`<form action="/redirected_true/index.html">`
  <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

In form tag I want the login button redirected to same folder \redirected_true\index.html  rather than it is redirecting to file:///C:/redirected_true/index.html? whats the problem.

Comment: You need to work your project on localhost or etc. not file system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run file from file:/// address, then you will be redirected there, if not using absolute path. Instead of /redirected, put there full url, with schema and domain name.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your project localhost or etc. it will working as you want. But in your case you run your project on local file system and '/' will send your project on base path.

Also the code below works in your localpath too:

```
<form action="redirected_true/index.html">
    <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, and I am admittedly not sure how this might be accepted in the community, you can do this:

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="redirect();">
```

and then

```
function redirect(){
    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
}
```

Totally untested, but I think it should be good.

Comment: whole form is like simple link, better to create simple <a> tag instead of redirect on submit or its easier to put url inside action attribute